# VBA: Worksheet.OnActivate

Tags: events, vba, excel

I have a method in my VBA code that needs to be assigned to a workbook.

I tried:

```
sht.Onactivate = "Sheet_Activate"
```

However, this does not work. How can I assign this method to the `worksheet.OnActivate` event using VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to assign a method to the event using the following code:

```
sheet.OnSheetActivate = "MyOwn_Activate"


Private Sub MyOwn_Activate()

    myForm.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code needs to apply to the worksheet staticly (meaning, this code should always be hooked with the worksheet's activate event), you can simply add the following in the worksheet's VBA editor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MyCodeHere()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Hanin. However, I am trying to assign a method in my VBA code to the onclick of sheet. Hence, I cannot use the Worksheet_Activate() direcly.

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA editor, in the Project Explorer
Select the worksheet, right click and select View Code
In the upper left drop down list choose Worksheet
In the upper right drop down list choose Activate

You can also do this in the Workbook object
gl hf